# DialogFragment dismiss() does not pop backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a simple DialogFragment that calls dismiss when exits, according to the documentation:

> public void dismiss()
>
> Dismiss the fragment and its dialog. **If the fragment was added to the**
>   **back stack, all back stack state up to and including this entry will**
>   **be popped**. Otherwise, a new transaction will be committed to remove
>   the fragment.

however, I found that the fragment is still on the backstack after calling **dismiss()** so I have to click back button to clear it. Does anyone know why ?

here's my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);

                Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);

                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new MyDialogFragment(), "test").addToBackStack("b").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I also found out that if I don't override **onBackPressed()**, the back button simple doesn't work, no matter how many fragments I add to the activity, the back button always exits the activity right away.

Comment: I think the behavior from the docs happens when you add the fragment as an actual dialog, by using the `show()` methods, and not when treating it like a normal fragment like you do in your code. The BACK button should also work unless you're doing something fishy.

Comment: Are you using `android.app.DialogFragment` or `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` ? And did you find any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm what [@Luksprog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002441/dialogfragment-dismiss-does-not-pop-backstack#comment46273097_29002441) said in his comment: the dialog must be started through [show(FragmentTransaction, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,%20java.lang.String)).

Note after looking the source: make sure to call [addToBackStack(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) on the supplied transaction or else it still won't work.

Answer (score 3):

That it's a wrong way to create a DialogFragment.

Never ever use the FragmentManager to show a DialogFragment. To be shown there are a method called show(FragmentTransacion, String).

In java:

```
MyDialogFragment mDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
mDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```

For another hand, to dismiss the dialog just do this:

```
mDialogFragment.dismiss()
```

Another think that I would like to highlight is that the MyDialogFragment class is defined inner onCreate method :'(
Please, define the class outside the method or in another file if you want :)

Good Look!

Answer (score 0):

```
dismiss()
findNavController().navigate(FirstBottomSheetDialogDirections.actionFirstSheetToSecondSheet())
```

This code is always the wrong thing to do: dismiss() is an asynchronous operation that doesn't actually dismiss anything immediately. That is unlike the navigate() which does immediately update the NavController's state, stacking the new dialog destination on top of the previous one.

This means that when the asynchronous dismiss actually happens, it correctly removes the dialog and, because it is a navigation stack, removes everything on top of it - including your second dialog. However, due to a bug in the DialogFragmentNavigator, we don't actually dismiss that second dialog, which is why it appears to work, despite everything actually already being internally out of sync (thus causing the later crash).

The correct way to pop a destination and navigate to a new destination as an atomic, immediate operation is to use popUpTo and popUpToInclusive. Therefore you can fix the sample app by removing the call to dismiss() and updating the action to pop the first dialog as part of the navigate call:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_firstSheet_to_secondSheet"
    app:destination="@id/secondSheet"
    app:popUpTo="@id/firstSheet"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

This correctly pops the first dialog off the back stack and then navigates to the new dialog destination.

please refer this link : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191073055